# D3D12 descriptor creation

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-12

Is creation of D3D12 descriptors free? By "free" I mean is there an allocation while calling `ID3D12Device::CreateShaderResourceView` or `ID3D12Device::CreateConstantBufferView` or `ID3D12Device::CreateUnorderedAccessView`? Can we call those function in application runtime? Or should that be called on application init?

Trying to figure out if creating descriptors on runtime can affect application performance.

Comment: Didn't find any mention about it in the documentation, so it might be implementation-dependent. Did you try asking directly on some MS directX support forums, or customer service?

Comment: Didn't find it either, I've decided to ask here first. I'll ask on MS forum and will share my knowlege if they respond me.

Comment: Just pasting the response from Jesse Natalie (DirectX team) in Discord: "_They in-place initialize the already-allocated descriptor memory. They should not allocate additional memory. They're not free from a performance perspective though, so calling them frequently can be a bottleneck._"